# How to create a tar of a chroot?

Tags: tar, chroot

I want to capture everything in a chroot but am unsure whether I need to first chroot into it to see the full filesystem/preserver permissions etc.  From outside the chroot, it seems like I would miss the root's home directory `/root`.  What is the way to fully capture a chroot, much like you could fully capture a VM?:

```
cd ~/mychroot
# Un-mount any previously mounted filesystems first?
# umount /proc
tar -cpzf /tmp/mychroot.tar.gz --one-file-system --exclude=/tmp --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/sys --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/media --exclude=/dev /    cp ~/mychroot/mychoort.tar.gz /path/to/somewhere/safe

sudo chroot ~/mychroot
# Un-mount any previously mounted filesystems first?
tar -cpzf /tmp/mychroot.tar.gz --one-file-system --exclude=/tmp --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/sys --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/media --exclude=/dev /    # Exit the chroot
exit
cp ~/mychroot/mychroot.tar.gz /path/to/somewhere/safe
```

Comment: is the answer anything other than `sudo tar -c mychroot -f mychroot.tar` ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to chroot to tar things. You can use the `--numeric-owner` option instead. Chroot is only necessary if you also want to record the (correct) owner/group names inside the tar archive, which is not strictly necessary in this case [when `/etc/passwd` etc. is part of the tar].

And without actually chrooting you also don't need to mount `/dev`, `/proc`, `/sys` etc. in the first place, so that's one headache removed.

The `--one-file-system` option is a false friend. It will simply give you an incomplete tar, since it skips any and all mountpoints. For example, some systems have static device nodes in `/dev` even before udev gets mounted there; they would be gone and as a result your system might not boot.

So don't ever use `--one-file-system` unless an incomplete result absolutely is what you want.

An alternative is bind mounting, for example for the root partition:

```
mkdir /mnt/root
mount --bind / /mnt/root
```

The bind mount does not carry submounts along with it so `/mnt/root` gives you the full picture of your root filesystem, including static nodes in `/dev/` and other things, if present. You can tar it in its entirety, without all the hassle of `--one-file-system` and dozens of `--exclude` options.

Comment: Just a note: these options are not sopported by tar, they are gtar specific.

Comment: @schily, they are supported by bsdtar as well. Actually, you'll probably want bsdtar anyway to be able to store extended attributes, sparseness (with -S). Note that --numeric-owner is more needed at extraction time. It's fine to omit it at creation time. Can `star` store extended attributes, ext2 file attributes, sparseness and things like that?

Comment: @schily, sorry -S is actually to _make_ sparse files when extracting archive members that are not necessarily sparse. bsdtar does attempt to store and restore sparseness when possible by default.

Comment: @schily, looks like `star` would do as well here with `-sparse -xattr -xfflags`.

Comment: I always assume GNU/Linux, unless the question gives reason not to.

Comment: And I assume the untar command outside the chroot will still work: `tar -xpvf mychoort.tar.gz`?

Comment: @tarabyte: if the tar archive was created with `--numeric-owner`, a simple `xpvf` is fine. Otherwise you have to use `--numeric-owner` at extraction time.

Comment: Any chance that for completness you can update your answer with a full tar and untar sequence for future viewers?

Comment: I always assume posix unless otherwise mentioned.

Comment: Btw. The features you are talking have been invented in star. Gtar uses different options for no known reason and gtar is still buggy or unusable with acls and xattrs. Gtar is a security risk as it does not extract acls correctly. Check the internals: all the headers start with SCHILY.

Comment: -S has a different meaning in star since 1985 - this is a year before the gtar precursor pdtar/sugtar exists.

Comment: @frostschutz, `tar --numeric-owner -cpzf /mychroot.tar.gz  /mnt/root` is returning a non-zero exit code (1) with message: `tar: /mnt/root: file changed as we read it`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out what `chroot(2)` is all about (user command `chroot(1)` is just a thin wrapper around the system call): It changes where the affected process sees `/`, so it can't (easily) escape/access files outside the targeted directory.

The "chroot" directory is just a bog-standard directory (probably set up with special contents by your friendly system administrator), so yo can manipulate it just like anything else.